# Binding, glue code and wrapper library

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, terminology

I many times saw terms `binding`, `glue`, and `wrapper` in a similar context and meaning(if we are talking about some "adapter code"). So what exactly means each of these terms? Is it a synonyms? Or what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

`binding`, `wrapper` and `glue` are - in this context specifically - are all *sort of* synonyms of each other and can *sort of* be used interchangeably..

`bind`, `wrap` and `glue` are all verbs which mean they're a word to describe an action, state or occurrence; even more-so they all revolve contextually around attachment. So yes - they are synonyms as far as the english language is concerned. However, concerning programming and the written paradigms used to describe ones actions within it may become more 'grey'.

Let us use an example. Directx and c#:

`binding` by definition is to "tie or fasten" something to something else, as is `glue` and to a lesser (but still valid) extent `wrap`. Which makes sense in this example as dx is is written and designed for `c++`, but there are libraries that `wrap` the `c++` code providing a useable library for c# programmers to use; inside which, the code `binds or glues` the original `c++` code to the `c#` equivalent - and vice versa - allowing these two (originally incompatible) sources to communicate.

So in using the `c#` alternative allows us access to the - if fully featured - functionality of the original `c++` version.

So when talking about a `wrapper` one can refer to the base as `binding` or `glue` code. However - in my opinion - `wrapper` is a much broader term contextually, of which contains the actions of `binding` and `'gluing'`.

This is my understanding - if somebody believes me mistaken, please don't hesitate to correct me.